# In linux, how to get the full path of a command I am using?

Tags: linux, path

How to get the full path of a command I am using?

for example, I have installed jdk into `/opt/Oracle/jdk1.7.0_25`, and my `PATH` looks like this:

```
/opt/Oracle/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin:/home/unimous/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games.
```

I want to get `/opt/Oracle/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/java` from `java`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
which java
```

should give you the complete path.

This also works for any other command in Linux, just use `which command_name`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your distribution, in debian and debian-based distros you have update-alternatives

And for your java you do for instance:

update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/opt/Oracle/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/java" 3

```
Help section on update-alternatives 

update-alternatives: --install needs <link> <name> <path> <priority>

Usage: update-alternatives [<option> ...] <command>

Commands:
  --install <link> <name> <path> <priority>
    [--slave <link> <name> <path>] ...
                           add a group of alternatives to the system.
  --remove <name> <path>   remove <path> from the <name> group alternative.
  --remove-all <name>      remove <name> group from the alternatives system.
  --auto <name>            switch the master link <name> to automatic mode.
  --display <name>         display information about the <name> group.
  --query <name>           machine parseable version of --display <name>.
  --list <name>            display all targets of the <name> group.
  --get-selections         list master alternative names and their status.
  --set-selections         read alternative status from standard input.
  --config <name>          show alternatives for the <name> group and ask the
                           user to select which one to use.
  --set <name> <path>      set <path> as alternative for <name>.
  --all                    call --config on all alternatives.

<link> is the symlink pointing to /etc/alternatives/<name>.
  (e.g. /usr/bin/pager)
<name> is the master name for this link group.
  (e.g. pager)
<path> is the location of one of the alternative target files.
  (e.g. /usr/bin/less)
<priority> is an integer; options with higher numbers have higher priority in
  automatic mode.

Options:
  --altdir <directory>     change the alternatives directory.
  --admindir <directory>   change the administrative directory.
  --log <file>             change the log file.
  --force                  allow replacing files with alternative links.
  --skip-auto              skip prompt for alternatives correctly configured
                           in automatic mode (relevant for --config only)
  --verbose                verbose operation, more output.
  --quiet                  quiet operation, minimal output.
  --help                   show this help message.
  --version                show the version.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're in bash:

```
type java
```

type is a built-in, which is usually a separate executable:

```
$ type type
type is a shell builtin
$ type which
which is hashed (/usr/bin/which)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `which`, use `type` command. The `which` command only gives path of where first command is found. The `type` command with `-a` gives all paths including aliases:

```
type -a java
```